# Using a Python Package Outside of Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

I wish to run a package, openquake; however, it was installed separately from Anaconda, which I am using to run python.

```
[centos modules]$ which python
~/anaconda2/bin/python
```

I have set openquake up and I believe it's installed correctly, however, when I try to run my script, I receive the following error:

```
[centos maxdist]$ python ../script.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 12, in <module>
    from openquake.hazardlib.source import ComplexFaultSource
ImportError: No module named openquake.hazardlib.source
```

I was wondering if I need to add a line to my script for it to find the openquake module for it to run successfully?  In general, what's the best way to run a python package that is installed outside of the main Anaconda python instance?  I am trying to avoid having to re-install openquake for Anaconda, as I was having a little bit of difficulty with that work-around.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If both environments, anaconda and default python that you installed the library for have the same python version, then

```
import sys    
sys.path.append(r'/path/to/package')    
from openquake.hazardlib.source import ComplexFaultSource
```

Check if this works. If the package is compiled for different version, then there will be an error. Also, I would suggest you to use one environment and avoid doing this for the sake of simplicity.